# How to distribute python3 code which contains external libraries

Tags: python-3.x, deployment, pycharm

I wrote a small script in python3 that uses numpy, matplotlib, and other libraries used by pyCharm CE in my linux machine.

I used pyCharm to code and create the virtual env.
The script works only inside pyCharm because of the dependencies.
And a friend of mine wants to use my script in a windows machine. I'm not sure if even he has python installed.

How can I run my script outside pyCharm, or how can I activate the virtual env created by pyCharm to run the script?

And

How I can create a package or something to give the script to my friend or anyone else to freely use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of going about to ask your friend to install `python3.x` and `pip` in his system. Meanwhile you create a `requirements.txt` which consists of the libraries that need to be installed and their versions in this format.

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.2.5
pytz==2019.2
sqlparse==0.3.0
psycopg2>=2.7,<3.0
```

Then ask your friend to run `pip install -r <path to requirements.txt>`. This will install all the required libraries and if there is no `OS` based dependencies then the project should run fine.

Another way of doing it in the case of bigger project where there are `OS` based dependencies is to use a `containerization` tool such as `docker`. Containerization lets you run projects, in other machines, which are dependent on various packages or environments which are available/installed in your machine.

For example: Imagine I created a python based application which is dependent on multiple packages in my `Debian` machine. I can build a `docker image` using `python3.x` as the base and install the required packages inside the `image` during the `build` time. It is fairly simple to do so. After doing so I can push the `image` to `docker hub` which is a registry to store `docker images`. Do mind that the `images` stored here are publicly available. If you are worried about that, you can use a private `AWS ECR` registry to store your `images`. Once I have pushed the `image`, anyone with access to the `image` can pull it and spin up a `container`. A `container` is an instance of an `image` which can run the applications/scripts/anything that the `image` is built to do. In order to be able to spin up `containers` they will need `docker` installed in their machine.

This way you can share your project and make it run in anyone's machine with as little hassle as possible. They will not need anything other than `docker` installed in their machine. Unlike `Virtual Machine` `docker containers` are not heavy on your machine.

In your case using `docker` you can build an `image` (much like an ISO image) with `python3.x` as base and install all the required packages such as `numpy`, `matplotlib` and other libraries, then copy the scripts required for the project to run into the `image` and push it to `docker hub` or a private registry of your choice. Then you can give your friend an access to the `image`. Your friend will need `Docker for Windows` installed in his machine in order to be able to spin up a `container` using the image you provided him with. This container will have your script running as it will have all the required dependencies installed in it by you while building the image itself.

For more info on `Docker`: https://www.docker.com/

Comment: Good, i'll try. I think it's a bit over-engeniering solution, because my script is really small, 270 lines of code beside the libraries. But if its the one solution I'll try to implement. Thanks.

Comment: If it is just python libraries and nothing major then you can just create a `requirements.txt` file and ask you friend to install `python` and `pip`. Then use the command `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install the required libraries and run the script.

Comment: I have updated the answer in case of a simple project

Comment: Anytime. If you can mark it as answer, it'll be helpful for other.